# Easy derivation to show that the curvature is $k(t)=\frac{|\alpha'\wedge\alpha''|}{{|\alpha'|}^3}$?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature

This is an exercise from Do Carmo's Differential Geometry which I doubt whether or not my working is correct.

Let $\alpha: I\to R^3$ be a regular parametrized curve (not necessarily by arc length) and let $\beta:J\to R^3$ be a reparametrization of $\alpha(I)$ by the arc length $s=s(t)$, measured from $t_0\in I$. Let $t=t(s)$ be the inverse function of $s$ and set $d\alpha/dt=\alpha'$, $d^2\alpha/dt^2=\alpha''$, etc. Prove that the curvature of $\alpha$ at $t\in I$ is

$$k(t)=\frac{|\alpha'\wedge\alpha''|}{{|\alpha'|}^3}$$

My attempt:

We first simplify the RHS: $\frac{|\alpha'\wedge\alpha''|}{{|\alpha'|}^3}=\frac{|\alpha'||\alpha''|}{{|\alpha'|}^3}=\frac{|\alpha''|}{{|\alpha'|}^2}$, where I used the definition $|a\wedge b|=|a||b|\cos\theta$.
Then we find the unit tangent vector of $\alpha$: $T(t)=\frac{\alpha'}{|\alpha'|}$.
So $\frac{dT}{ds}=\frac{dT}{dt}\frac{dt}{ds}=T'(t)\frac{1}{|\alpha'|}$.

Now it is very tempting to write $T'(t)=\frac{\alpha''}{|\alpha'|}$, then we have $\frac{dT}{ds}=\frac{\alpha''}{{|\alpha'|}^2}$ and since $\frac{dT}{ds}=kn$ where $n$ is the unit normal vector, so $k=\frac{|\alpha''|}{{|\alpha'|}^2}$.

I really doubt my correctness, the part that I found it hard is to find $T'(t)$. And I think my working $T'(t)=\frac{\alpha''}{|\alpha'|}$ is wrong since the denominator might also be a function of $t$. But I am not sure how to fix it. Helps are really greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: $|\alpha'\wedge\alpha''|$ is supposed to be the cross product, can you explain why you can change it to $|\alpha'|| \alpha''|$?

Comment: @LeeKM I used the definition of cross product $|a\times b|=|a||b|\sin\theta$.

Comment: an easy way is to (1) write $\alpha$ as the composition of the arc length parametrization $\beta$ and the arc length function $l_{\alpha}(t) = \int_{t_0}^t |\alpha ' (k) |dk$; (2) differentiate $\alpha$ once and twice,, then everything should be clear

Answer (score 1):

Let $s'(t)=\left|\gamma'(t)\right|$. Then, the second derivative with respect to arclength is
$$
\frac1{s'}\left[\frac{\gamma'}{s'}\right]'=\frac{\gamma''s'-\gamma's''}{s'^3}\tag{1}
$$
Since $\frac{\gamma'}{s'}$ is a unit vector, the vector in $(1)$ is perpendicular to it. Therefore, it has the same length as
$$
\frac{\gamma'}{s'}\times\frac{\gamma''s'-\gamma's''}{s'^3}=\frac{\gamma'\times\gamma''}{\left|\gamma'\right|^3}\tag{2}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\kappa=\frac{\left|\gamma'\times\gamma''\right|}{\left|\gamma'\right|^3}\tag{3}
$$

Comment: I don't follow your second derivative, how?

Comment: @help do you mean equation 1?

Comment: @nhmwhhxx I see this answer has the same $s'(t)$ equation initially, but what happens after that, I have no clue. I see we both came up with an $s'''$ but I don't know if they're exactly the same. I just don't understand this answer in comparison to what I did.

Comment: @help I'm confused on where you see the $s'''$ in this answer, am I missing something?

Comment: @nhmwhhxx The denominator of the right hand side of equation 1. Isn't that the same thing I have in my formulation?

Comment: @help: I am not sure what formulation you are referring to. There is no $s'''$ in my answer. $s'^3$ is the cube of the first derivative, not the third derivative.