# Determining the curvature of an Ellipse

Tags: real-analysis, curvature

I have the following parameterization of an Ellipse:

$$x=a \cos (\omega t),\space \space \space y=b\sin(\omega t),\space \space \space \omega=const., \space \space \space a,b \in \Bbb R$$

I want to determine the **curvature** $\color{blue}{\kappa}$ and the **radius of curvature** $\color{red}{\rho}$

I know that the curvature is the absolute value of the unit-tangent vector $\hat{e}_t$ differentiated with respect to arc-length:

$$\color{blue}{\kappa}=\lvert \frac{d \hat{e}_t}{ds}\lvert$$

The radius of curvature is:

$$\color{red}{\rho}=\frac{1}{\color{blue}{\kappa}}$$

**My questions:**

1. Am I right in saying that curvature just tells me how much my curve bends at a certain point?
2. How do I calculate $\frac{d \hat{e}_t}{ds}$?

I know how to get $\hat{e}_t$:

$$\dot{\vec{r}}(t)=\begin{bmatrix}-a \omega \sin(\omega t) \\b \omega \cos(\omega t)\end{bmatrix} \implies \frac{\dot{\vec{r}}(t)}{\lvert \dot{\vec{r}}(t)\rvert}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2\omega^2\sin^2(\omega t)+b^2\omega^2\cos(\omega t)}} \begin{bmatrix}-a \omega \sin(\omega t) \\b \omega \cos(\omega t)\end{bmatrix}=\hat{e}_t$$

However, how do I differentiate this with respect to arc-length $s$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question, the “right”ness depends on how precise you want to define “bends”.  But if you look at the expression $\left|\frac{d\hat e_t}{ds}\right|$, you can interpret it as the speed at which the unit tangent vector rotates as you move uniformly along the curve.

For the second, the arc-length functions along ellipses are not integrable in elementary terms (they are the pathway to the study of *elliptic functions*).   Instead, you might find one of the equivalent formulas for curvature more helpful:
$$
    \kappa(t) = \frac{\left|\dot{\hat e_t}(t)\right|}{\left|\dot{\vec r}(t)\right|} = \frac{\left|\dot{\vec r}(t) \times \ddot{\vec r}(t)\right|}{\left|\dot{\vec r}(t)\right|^3}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The first part makes sense. For the second part I found another formula in my textbook:

$$\kappa(t)=\frac{\lvert \lvert \hat{e}_t \rvert \rvert}{\lvert \lvert \dot{\vec{x}}(t) \rvert \rvert}$$ 

but I don't see how I can get from my original formula for $\kappa$ to that. Any ideas?

Comment: I should add that I would prefer using another formula than the one with the cross product. I am really having difficulties understanding why $\lvert ds \rvert$ is equal to $\lvert \dot{\vec{r}}(t)\rvert$

Comment: @bluemoon: The formula using the cross product (which is justified in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1463306)) is probably the easiest. On the other comment, $\left|\mathrm{d}s\right|=\left|\dot{\vec{r}}(t)\right|\mathrm{d}t$.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks! Now it all makes sense.